# Change ticks style

Tags: plotting, syntax, ticks

Consider the following frame ticks and plot:

```
TicksPlotx = 
  Join[Flatten[
    Table[{i*10^j, ""}, {i, 2, 9, 1}, {j, -3, 0, 1}], {1, 
     2}], {{10^-3, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\)", 
     0.03}, {10^-2, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-2\)]\)", 
     0.03}, {10^-1, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-1\)]\)", 
     0.03}, {1, 1, 0.03}}];

LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-4, 1.5}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {TicksPlotx, None}}]
```

Everything is well except for the continuation of the ticks for which I set the length (those are $10^{i}, i = -3,-2,-1,0$) to the bottom, outside the plot (please see the attached screenshot, where I mark the problem in red). Could you please tell me how to remove this continuation?

[image]

Comment: This works well on the free cloud account. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Syed : I am using 12.1.0.0.

Comment: `{{10^-3, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\)", 
   { 0.03,0.05}}`:  i.e., use positive and negative length specs for x-ticks. In your case, make the negative lengths zero.

Comment: @Syed : Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Please communicate this to WRI support. When you hear from them, please modify the title of the post to add a reference to your version. In addition, you can add the bugs tag as well as a bugs header to this post.

Comment: Works in MMA version 13.1 Windows 10